# How do you generate a token for creating a WordPress user in angular 4

Tags: wordpress, angular5, wp-api

Can someone explain:

```
let header = new Headers({"Authorization": "Bearer "+token});
```

How should i get that value for the token?

I am using `wp-api-angular`

here is a code example:

```
signUpForm() {
  const headers = new Headers({
    'Authorization': 'Bearer' + this.token
  });

  this.wpApiUsers.create(
    this.newUser,
    { headers: headers })
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    }
  );

}
```

I now Have This:

```
signUpForm() {
  this.http.post('https://website.com/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token', {
    username: 'admin',
    password: 'password'
  }).subscribe(data => {
    if (data['token']) { // if token is returned
      this.token = data['token'];

      const headers = new Headers({
        'Authorization': 'Bearer' + this.token
      });

      const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

      this.http.post(
        'https://website.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users',
        this.newUser,
        options
      );

    }

  });


}
```

But now I am getting this error:

Argument of type '{ headers: Headers; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestOptionsArgs'.
  Types of property 'headers' are incompatible.
    Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type 'Headers'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
      Property 'keys' is missing in type 'Headers'.
const headers: Headers

Answer (score 0):

The token allows you to have authorization to access data that can't be accessed by a non authenticated user, it is generated when you successful sign-in.

You first need to request the token (Sign-in), for that you must do a POST request with the username and password, the response will have the token that you should save and use after for other requests that requires authorization.

```
this.http.post('http://YOUR_DOMAIN/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token', {
    username: this.user.login,
    password: this.user.password
  }).subscribe(
    (data) => {
      if (data['token']) { // if token is returned
        console.log(data['token']); // Token
      }
    }, (error) => {} // Authentication errors
);
```

Complete tutorial: https://www.sitepoint.com/angular-wordpress-wp-api-angular/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, it help me out allot. I added another error above. Is it possible you could take a look?

Comment: You can set the `const options` as this: `{ headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.token } }`

Comment: Or right this: `{ headers: { new HttpHeaders({Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.token })}`. The mentioned problem of Headers duplicate is presented due to the use of deprecated `@angular/http`, take care of use only `@angular/common/http`.